# Vue js, Vue js method returning undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue class

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [],
      currentSort:'name',
      currentSortDir:'asc',
      companies: []
    };
  },
  async created() {
    this.storage.tasks++;
    try {
      this.tasks = await Monitor.Task.getTasks();
      this.companies = await Monitor.getCompanies();
    } catch (code) {
      this.notify("danger", "Не удалось загрузить задачи", code);
    } finally {
      this.storage.tasks--;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    mappedTasks() {
      return _.chain(this.tasks)
          .sort((a,b) => {
            let modifier = 1;
            if(this.currentSortDir === 'desc') modifier = -1;
            if(a[this.currentSort] < b[this.currentSort]) return -1 * modifier;
            if(a[this.currentSort] > b[this.currentSort]) return 1 * modifier;
            return 0;
          })
          .map(it => {
            let statusText;
            switch (it.status) {
              case "NOT_COMPLETED":
                statusText = "Ожидает выполнения";
                break;
              case "COMPLETED":
                statusText = "Завершено";
                break;
              case "CANCELED":
                statusText = "Отменено";
                break;
              default:
                statusText = "Неизвестно";
            }
            const companyName = this.getCompanyById(it.companyId).name;

            let updated
            if(it.updatedAt !== null) {
              updated = Moment(it.updatedAt).utcOffset(TIME_ZONE).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
            }

            const values = {
              statusText,
              createdAt: Moment(it.createdAt).utcOffset(TIME_ZONE).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
              updatedAt: updated,
              companyId: companyName
            };


            return _.assign({}, it, values);
          })
          .value();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    sort:function(s) {
      if(s === this.currentSort) {
        this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir==='asc'?'desc':'asc';
      }
      this.currentSort = s;
    },
    getCompanyById(id) {
      return this.companies.find(company => company.id === id);
    }
  }
}
```

The proplem that in method getCompanyById this.companies is undefined therefore method doens't return company. I tried to make to make method async and like this:

```
async getCompanyById() {
  let  companies = await Monitor.getCompanies()
  return companies
}
```

In this case, I have that status of companies is pending. I don't undenstand why in computed.mappedTask I can't get companies from async created unlike tasks

Comment: This is fundamental to how async/await works. It returns the promise of a result, not result itself. This would require a function that uses getCompanyById to be async too, while Vue computeds are synchronous only. You should retrieve the results from getCompanyById before mappedTasks is called with meaningful result. One of possible ways is to not render the component before data it relies on are fetched